# Unable to import pymysql on python3, throws import error

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

Unable to import pymysl in python-3.6, on venv on a debian machine tried all possible options.Not getting any error while installing.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo apt-get install python-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
sudo pip3  install mysqlclient
sudo apt-get install python3-pymysql
sudo apt-get install python3.6-dev libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip3 install pymysql
sudo pip3  install mysql-connector-python
```

[image]

Comment: sudo pip3  show pymysql
Name: PyMySQL
Version: 0.9.3
Summary: Pure Python MySQL Driver
Home-page: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/
Author: yutaka.matsubara
Author-email: yutaka.matsubara@gmail.com
License: "MIT"
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages

Comment: python 3.6 or python 3.5 ? Your interpreter is 3.5. Ensure that `pip3` is a soft link to `pip3.5` and if not, retry in an interpreter `python3.6`.